# Use named scope with has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have the following model:

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many   :users, :through => :participants do
                 def manager
                     where("participants.role = ?", "Manager").first
                 end
               end
```

This allows me to do the following in my controller and views

```
@board.users.manager
```

Is there a way to use a named_scope to be able to get the manager for a board as follows:

```
@board.manager
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample solution:

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many   :users, :through => :participants do
    def manager
      where("participants.role = ?", "Manager").first
    end
  end

  delegate :manager, :to => :users

end
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mauricio. It works like a charm and am using it for so many other things.